# How do I delete an item in a smartpy list

Tags: smartpy

I am trying to figure out how to delete an item from my list that I created with `possible_values = sp.range(0, 100, step = 1)` I have tried `possible_values.pop(index)`, that doesnt work. I have tried `del possible_values[index]`, that didnt work. It also doesnt seem to let me define by index such as `possible_values[index] = -1`. Is this possible to do with a `list` or will I need to use a `map`? Also If I need to use a `map` how do I create a range with a map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not possible to do random access or edition on lists.
The only reasonable building block that you have is matching the first element.

https://smartpy.io/docs/types/lists/#match-a-list-and-expose-its-head-and-tail

Maps and sets are much better structures if you want to add and remove elements.

About range/map.
In full generality, you need to do it with a for loop. See example in the init method of https://smartpy.io/ide?template=state_channel_games/models/nim.py. Note that you also need a local variable.

If your map has always the same shape and size (and doesn’t depend on any dynamic parameter) when you create it; you can also simply expose it directly as you would do in Python (with a constant, dict comprehension, etc.). This would inline the map inside your Michelson code.